# How to get Object URL(link) from AWS S3 using rails (API JSON Response)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, amazon-s3

i have an app where i can upload images and videos from the admin dashboard this is all working perfectly, the only thing that i couldn't do is how can i ( is it possible ) to get the object url and respond it as json ,

currently i'm getting this response :

```
{

images: [
"https://promoteur-api.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com//rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBNQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--f4fdd1c0fd4b07b03b0282a63c8fa1ca31d310c6/41567.png",
]
}
```

i want it to be something like this:

```
{

images: [
"https://promoteur-api.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/AWS_OBJECT_ID",
]
}
```

this is my #serializer.rb

```
class ProjetSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  attributes :id, :nom, :gouvernorat, :localite, :surface, :description, :en_cours, :fini,  :images
  
  def images
    object.images.map do |image|
      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_url(image, only_path: true) if object.images.attached?
    end
  end

end
```

i need to access directly to images URLs to display them in my flutter app, if u have an easier way to do it instead of this please let me know ,

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `service_url` method for object service URL

New Seriliazer

```
class ProjetSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :nom, :gouvernorat, :localite, :surface, :description, :en_cours, :fini,  :images
  
  def images
    object.images.map do |image|
      image.service_url if object.images.attached?
    end
  end
end
```

But this url will be expired after a while

If you want change expire time

```
# config/initializers/active_storage.rb
Rails.application.config.active_storage.service_urls_expire_in = 1.hour
```

Comment: Thank you @Kemal_AKIN , i tried image.service_url , but it gives me a nil error 
`bad URI(is not URI?): nil`
i remeber i that i tried this one before couldn't fix this error tho :/

Comment: I think you are using the disk service on local development environment
Can you describe it that way and try
`ActiveStorage::Current.host = 'http://localhost:3000'`

Comment: that was the problem, i switched my active storage from local to amazon it did the job on i'm going to check it now on production   `config.active_storage.service = :amazon`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is correct, perhaps you've not set the host url in your env file? If not, add `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'this_is_base_url.com'` in `development.rb`

Comment: thank you @TTD , i have that set in my application_controller here is the line i'm using 
`class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'https://promoteur-api.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com'
end`
with this i got the first half of the desired url, all i need to do is to somehow retrive the ObjectID from the s3 storage , to make it like this 
`https://promoteur-api.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/5vf79jb3xb0qqkdhsh6jww4irpls`

Comment: Try to replace `rails_blob_url` with `service_url`

Comment: gives me this Error `bad URI(is not URI?): nil`